# Antlr 4 generates Swift mixed with Python

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I'm trying to use Antlr 4 to generate Swift code that can parse Python 3 code.  Antlr 4 generates a mixture of Python and Swift in the generated Swift files.  The issue repros with a very simple install of a the latest Antlr4 jar and the latest Python3 grammar on latest MacOS.

I'm using the latest Antlr 4 on a nearly clean install of Mac OS Monterey 12.4.  Specifically, I'm using `antlr-4.10.1-complete.jar` and the `Python3.g4` file from HEAD of master (`2228b048`) of https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4

I'm following these instructions:

https://github.com/antlr/antlr4/blob/master/doc/swift-target.md

I'm generating the Swift using:

```
# grammars-v4 is a clean copy of https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4 at HEAD of master (`2228b048`) 
cd grammars-v4
antlr4 -Dlanguage=Swift ./python/python3-py/Python3.g4 -o ../antlr-swift-python/
```

This generates 4 Swift files.  The generated `Python3Lexer.swift` file contains a mixture of Swift (the parsing language) and Python (the parsed language).

The file begins with some Python, then later switches to Swift.

```
// Generated from Python3.g4 by ANTLR 4.10.1

from antlr4.Token import CommonToken
import re
import importlib

# Allow languages to extend the lexer and parser, by loading the parser dynamically
module_path = __name__[:-5]
language_name = __name__.split('.')[-1]
language_name = language_name[:-5]  # Remove Lexer from name
LanguageParser = getattr(importlib.import_module('{}Parser'.format(module_path)), '{}Parser'.format(language_name))

import Antlr4

open class Python3Lexer: Lexer {

    internal static var _decisionToDFA: [DFA] = {
```

Note the Python-style imports, comments and code followed by Swift import and Swift class definition.

This continues throughout the file. Here's another snippet demonstrating the issue:

```
    public
    static let VOCABULARY = Vocabulary(_LITERAL_NAMES, _SYMBOLIC_NAMES)


    @property
    def tokens(self):
        try:
            return self._tokens
        except AttributeError:
            self._tokens = []
            return self._tokens
```

Here we see a Swift property followed by a Python method.

- I've just installed Antlr 4 and grammars-v4; I haven't edited any of its files.
- I was able to successfully generate the Swift runtime and build that framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The python3 grammar doesn’t appear to be set up for a Swift target.

Semantic predicates and actions will, very often (almost always) introduce code in the target language.  It takes a lot of discipline to make a grammar “target agnostic”, and for some languages, it’s just not possible (given Python’s reliance on indentation, it would probably be impossible to create a target agnostic version of the grammar). The python3 grammar seems to have going to lengths to facilitate multiple targets by using base classes as the hook to inject target specific code, but the is no implementation of those base classes for Swift.

I see targets for Python, C#, Java, and JavaScript, but not one for Swift.